# Java api to check if hbase is up and running

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, hbase

I'm trying to handle failure scenarios when connecting to HBase. Currently, I've a check to see if HBase is running with `HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);`. But this api would thrown an exception in case of `MasterNotRunning` or `ZookeeperConnectionException` only after ~40 seconds. So, I tried setting the following retries, `hbase.client.retries.number = 1` and `zookeeper.recovery.retry = 1`. This got me the exception to be handled in 6-7 seconds. But, I need a much quicker way to know if HBase cluster is running, since I'm logging to HBase in a synchronous call within my application.

Answer (score 4):

What about checking the connection in this way:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HMasterInterface;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcEngine;
...

public static boolean isRunning() {
    boolean result = false;
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.clear();
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "myhost");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    conf.set("hbase.master", "myhost:60000");

    RpcEngine rpcEngine = null;
    try {

        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress("myhost", 60000);
        rpcEngine = HBaseRPC.getProtocolEngine(conf);
        HMasterInterface master = rpcEngine.getProxy(HMasterInterface.class,
                HMasterInterface.VERSION, isa, conf, 1000);
        result = master.isMasterRunning();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    }
    finally {
        if (rpcEngine != null) {
            rpcEngine.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note: I assumed here version >= 0.94.5

Comment: This check threw MasterNotRunningException instantaneously. Thank you. But this works only if Master is not running I think. I also want to handle all exceptions like ZookeeperConnectionException, NoRegionServerException and the like for a given HBase cluster. Also, the Zookeeper Socket Connection Exception is been thrown in 4-5 seconds which is a little better. Also, I've tried                    HBaseAdmin administer = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
administer.isMasterRunning(); which takes around the same time.

Comment: Yes it keeps throwing exceptions. Please see my edited answer, I've rewritten the method.

Comment: What version of HBase would this be in? I can't find the method getProtocolEngine() in 0.94.1. BTW, would the check isMasterRunning() handle all the failure cases if any components of HBase cluster is down ? Just not sure.

Comment: I assumed here version >= `0.94.5`, I added it to my answer. This method can tell you way faster (in my case < 1000ms) if HBase is up and running, which was the original question.
Since you use an older HBase (which you didn't mention) in which `getProtocolEngine()` is private you can either try to call it via reflection or need to check the `HBaseRPC` source code
for alternatives (e.g:getProxy() ?) if you want to give it a try.

Comment: @LorandBendig Useful solution; upvoted :-). But shouldn't the `"myhost", 60000` part be read from Zookeeper? :^)

Comment: Can you provide in the latest APIs?